# Who does the data explorer think I am John.Doe

Tags: support, data-explorer, users

I logged into data-explorer for the first time 9I have viewed others' queries but have not created one myself). When I log in with the StackExchange Open Id provider, I am shown as `john.doe13574`.

[image]

This does not happen when I login to a new stackexchange site, my details are recogniozed and fetched from my profile.

Is this an expected behaviour? Strangely, my picture is recognized correctly so the system "knows" me (I know the picture is from Gravatar, but the system knows what details to send to Gravatar)